# How to use .htaccess to redirect sub domain to another folder, not URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have hosting with no domain pointing to it at present (because I changed the A record to point to another host).

How can I use .htaccess to point my subdomain to the root of the hosting? Also, can the .htaccess file sit in the subdomain's folder because if it goes in the root, I assume it won't be called because the domain points elsewhere.

My folder structure is like this:

- the root is: /httpdocs
- the subdomain is: /subdomains/old/httpdocs

Comment: so is the subdomain's complete path: /httpdocs/subdomains/old/httpdocs?

Comment: no - subdomain's folder is not a child of the website's root which I think is causing me issues. It's Plesk setup if that helps?

Comment: I'm confused on the location of the subdomain. Is the A record pointing to the same machine? is the subdomain just outside of the web root and located elsewhere on the same server?

Comment: A record of main site is pointing to a different host. The A record of the sub is pointing the current host. Thus it's not really a "sub" domain but it is old.mydomain.com

Comment: This is not the answer to this question, but this is what solved my problem using Plesk's inbuilt functionality: http://serverfault.com/questions/34676/using-subdomain-to-setup-domain

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not mistaken when I read the question. Here you can't use `.htaccess` to point your subdomain to the root of the hosting.

On your case you can point your subdomain to the root of the hosting by setting your subdomain exactly the same IP address before you changed your A record.

Say old setting of your A record it point to IP 123.123.123.123

```
A 123.123.123.123
```

Now say you have change your A record point to another host say IP 456.456.456.456. So all you need is set your sub domain to the same IP of your A record before it was changed.

```
A 456.456.456.456
subdomain 123.123.123.123
```